# Getting start with React and Material Ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm starting to understand to work with Material Ui with React, I'm getting difficult to customize the components.

I have this example of the AppBar:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';

const styles = {
title: {
   cursor: 'pointer',
 },
};

const AppBarExampleIconButton = () => (

<AppBar

title={<span styles={styles.title}>Portofolio</span>}

iconElementRight={<FlatButton label="Save" />} />

);

export default AppBarExampleIconButton;
```

I can customize the title, but I want to customize the AppBar, in the documentation the Style object Override the inline-styles of the root element. But I'm not understanding out it works, could someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried googling "react bootstrap tutorial"?

Comment: For the most constructive feedback, you should do your best to research this topic on your own. If you encounter *specific* questions during your research that you have trouble answering yourself, you can ask them on StackOverflow for specific answers! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a guide to constructing good questions.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser !! i understand !! i will try my best !! thank y

Comment: really don't understand why this is off-topic - it may well be a case of RTFM but it is a specific developer problem with the technology he lists.

Anyway the answer @Hseleiro is found in the documentation here: http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes specifically it says that in the styles: "There is also one key for each component so you can use to customize them individually"

Comment: also suggesting googling "react bootstrap tutorial" is pretty unhelpful as the question is about material-ui not bootstrap.

Comment: Its because the question was about react , and then i change the subject to material ui, because i was having negative reviews and my answer was not made correcly, Thank you very much. Im tring material Ui now

Comment: ah my apologies to @SteveGreatrex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depend on of what you try to do you can customize the AppBar in a multiple way. One of them is if you only want to change the color etc to make a theme.js file and import it inside [MuiThemeProvider](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes)

You do this in the root file of your app. Ex

```
// Material Setup
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

// Our Own Theme
import theme from './layout/theme';

const Root = () =>
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(theme)}>
    <YourApp />
  </MuiThemeProvider>;
```

SO if you want to do this inline like you say you make a object inside your styles object who is the css you want to apply to the appbar.

```
const styles = { 
  appbar: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  }
}
```

And you call it as a props for the AppBar component

```
<AppBar style={styles.appbar} />
```

Also if you look at the docs [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar) you can see the title have is own style props for him call `titleStyle`

Hope that can help you figured out.